# Replies to deleted account's answers appear in Inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox, deleted-accounts

I had my Gaming account deleted a while back (for reasons I won't go into here).

Earlier today, my inbox notified me about a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/91958) to one of my [answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40772) on Gaming.

I assume this is a bug.

Edit: A year has gone by and this is still happening on questions that were migrated to Gaming from another site on the network.